# How to access subquery table in the main query with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

```
select  m1.id, m1.status, at.view_data, at.view_graph, ta.tag_string
from
access_tbl at, image_campaign_tbl m1
RIGHT JOIN 
        (select
        GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as tag_string , c.image_campaign_id
        from campaign_tags_tbl c,tag_tbl t
        where c.tag_id=t.id 
        $tag_q
        group by c.image_campaign_id
        ) as ta
ON ta.image_campaign_id=m1.id
where
        m1.client_id =$client_id
        and m1.client_id = at.client_id
    $prev_filter
limit $start,$end;
```

Error message:

> in LOGS: DBD::mysql::db selectall_arrayref failed: Unknown column 't.name' in 'where clause' at /home/sakthi/rtads/Project/pm/Image/UI.pm line 2536.**

In Perl Module, I'm passing the same value of $tag_q to the $prev_filter to get the Pagination of filter based on TAGS values in the next page

```
if ( $prev_filter eq '' ) {
    $prev_filter =
        $search_clist_q . ' '
      . $tag_q . ' '
}
```

From the error msg, I got the error which I'm doing. Since I'm trying to access the table of subquery in the main query, this error is happening.

So I want to know how to access the tag_string(or)t.name outside the subquery.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with access of `tag_string` outside of the subquery. As per the error, I think that there is no column called `name` in `tag_tbl`. Please recheck that.

Comment: You're mixing implicit (comma) and explicit joins. Because of the precedence this is a sure way to such errors, see [SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html): *However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur.*

Comment: Is there anyway, i can use (subquery) TA's column like " TA.tag_string " in the main query? Kindly Let me know

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i suggest you to avoid use of old school syntax for jointures (`FROM table1, table2,... WHERE table1.column1 = table2.column2 AND ...`).

Here is the query that seems to return what you're looking for:

```
SELECT IC.id
    ,IC.status
    ,A.view_data
    ,A.view_graph
    ,TA.tag_string
FROM access_tbl A
INNER JOIN image_campaign_tbl IC ON IC.client_id = A.client_id
                                   AND IC.client_id = $client_id
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT CT.image_campaign_id
                  ,GROUP_CONCAT(T.name) AS [tag_string]
            FROM campaign_tags_tbl CT
            INNER JOIN tag_tbl T ON T.id = CT.tag_id
            GROUP BY CT.image_campaign_id) TA ON TA.image_campaign_id = IC.id
WHERE <Your filters here>
LIMIT $start, $end
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Joel salamin, i tried with your way of code. but i didnt get any output. I'm in need to use Right join with my sub query.

Comment: The code which i pasted works fine and displays the 1st ten outputs. But when i try to go for the second page, the pagination is not working. In the sense, i need to pass the Filter query and thats the place where i'm facing problem.

Comment: Is there anyway, i can use (subquery) TA's column like " TA.tag_string " in the main query? Kindly Let me know

Comment: @Sakthivel Do you want to check if `tag_string` contains a provided tag?